# Changing the api name of a custom object

Tags: api

I have created an object,created fields in it and wrote all visualforce pages and classes. Although I have changed the name of the object its API name has not changed. I want to change the API name as well. I don't want to create a the object again from scratch as it has a lot of fields in it.

What steps should I take to change the API name....

```
Object__c to Object1__c
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming it isn't a released/managed Object, you can change the Objects API name by clicking Edit (Setup->Create->Objects) next to the Object:

[image]

Then, simply type in a new name and hit save:

[image]

It will probably warn you about making changes to names for existing integrations, but assuming you're ok with that just ignore.  If you have dependent classes that reference the object, you will need to 'un-reference' it first before you can change it.

For example, in the example below I would need to go into all of these classes etc. and remove any reference to the DocumentSequenceNumber__c object:

[image]

Comment: In Tense didn't observed that field...Anywayz thanks for ur Answer @Phil