# Change API Name of Custom Object (How to remove reference of class to object)

Tags: apex, custom-object

I have a similar requirement as this post. 
[Changing the api name of a custom object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/changing-the-api-name-of-a-custom-object)

The answer was to remove any reference to the custom object.

1. Does this mean I have to comment out referenced code?
2. If I have already deployed the custom object to production, what steps should I do to also make change to the production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with a sandbox:

1. Comment out all references to the object in the code base and test methods
2. Deploy new code to production
3. Change object Name in Production and Sandbox
4. Update all code in sandbox to reference the new name and uncomment
5. Clone previous changeset
6. Deploy new changeset to production

Comment: @sfdcnoob n.b. this probably means some scheduled downtime for your users as you will be removing functionality in step 2 that won;t get restored until step 6